# ver 12.04 does not install on Proline Notebook

Tags: system-installation

Trying to install ver 12.04 from a CD onto a Proline Notebook (M54SE)
The system starts to install, but comes up with error.
[55.095664] Buffer I/O error on device ZRAM0. Logical block 55189.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

According the [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zram) wiki article on ZRAM it is something to do with aiding with SSDs.

Double check your RAM with memtest86+ from the CD to make sure that all is well, chances are you have a bad stick of RAM.

Comment: Cole, I tried your suggestion, but the memtest came up clean.

Comment: @JPViljoen Try running `gnome-disks` to open the disk manager in ubuntu from the live session. This will present you with some information regarding the disk then. ZRAM is supposed to be a block on RAM though, so I still think it is a stick of RAM but it could also be a fluke. I was having an issue with a fatal call to the RAM when installing XBMCbuntu (Ubuntu 12.04) and that was my issue but it was not utilizing ZRAM, it was directly referencing the RAM. **TL;DR** try `gnome-disks` and look for the [disk manager](http://askubuntu.com/a/59077/150173)'s attributes for more info.