# I can't format my flash drive

Tags: disk, drive

I'm trying to format my flash drive via Disks:

[image]

but every time I get this error:

[image]

What should I do? Thanks!

Comment: Could you please add the output of `tail -n 70 /var/log/syslog`? (This command will print the last 70 lines of your system log.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to format USB drive with Disks (udisks-error-quark, 0)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/377253/unable-to-format-usb-drive-with-disks-udisks-error-quark-0) and also see [this post](http://itsfoss.com/how-to-format-a-sd-card-or-usb-drive-in-ubuntu-12-10/)

Answer (score 1):

I can see that the drive is not mounted. Maybe you should mount it first.