# I can't install Ubuntu or any linux distro

Tags: boot, partitioning, system-installation, hard-drive

First I apologize, I know that my English isn't very good.
Now, I'm in live-CD from **Ubuntu 16.04 AMD64**

I tried to install Elementary OS.
I failure and my HDD lost all of my information (Windows, docs, etc)...

Then, I tried to install Q4OS from Windows executable file (`.exe`).
I failure, black screen with white words.
I can't remember those words, but the idea is that Q4OS hasn't boot manager and OS information.
The HDD that I select to install the OS wasn't formatted.

Then, I tried to install **Ubuntu 16.04** and I'm here, in Live-CD interface and writing to you.

In all of then cases I has the same problem:
Unable to create X or Y partition (frequently exchange area - in Spanish "**area de intercambio"**).

Now, in Live-CD I try to format the HDD disks (my pc has 2 HDD >> one: 1TB, the other one: 80GB).

I can't, I try using `Gparted`, y try using Disks and y try using `Cfdisk` console command and I can't do anything, neither create partition table or format any disk...

GParted do nothing, only try to create partition table but before the process nothing changes...
`Cfdisk`, the same case, try but when I reload (quit and enter again) nothing changes.

And Disks try but the information after the process is the same that before.

> Error formatting volume: error synchronizing after formatting with type "ext4" Timed out waiting for object
>
> usdisks-error-quark, 0

Please help me installing Ubuntu (yes, I can install again Windows but that isn't the idea).

If its relevant: I have an **GA-970A-DS3P** and **RX Radeon 550**

OS INSTALLATION:
[image: OS INSTALLATION]

GPARTED BEFORE:
[image: GPARTED BEFORE]

GPARTED IN:
[image: GPARTED IN]

GPARTED AFTER:
[image: GPARTED AFTER]

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/a/377396/367990

Comment: Thanks you! That dont works :(, i can do not anything then i cant create partition table

Comment: what does the information about the *unallocated* space in `gparted` say, since there is a red warning sign?

Comment: the warning says 

/dev/sda: unrecognised disk label

Comment: @ZahirObandoArenas: are you sure? your picture is showing `sdb` as the selected drive (with the unallocated space) and now you are writing about `sda`...?!?

Comment: Oh, im sorry, i challenge the device, but the information was the same in sdb device; now im trying formatting sdb (80gb HDD) to ext2 with Disks with the option "overwrite existing data with zeroes" (slow), maybe with that process the device can recognize the disk

Comment: here is an screenshot from Gparted SDB [https://ibb.co/dQ4yBc ]

Comment: THE LOG IS>>>>>>>>>
GParted 0.25.0 --enable-libparted-dmraid --enable-online-resize

Libparted 3.2
Create Primary Partition #1 (ext2, 74.50 GiB) on /dev/sdb  00:00:01    ( ERROR )
      
create empty partition  00:00:01    ( SUCCESS )
      
path: /dev/sdb1 (partition)
start: 2048
end: 156248063
size: 156246016 (74.50 GiB)
clear old file system signatures in /dev/sdb1  00:00:00    ( ERROR )
libparted messages    ( INFO )
      
/dev/sdb: unrecognised disk label

Comment: well... there is a wide variety of possible causes and solutions: please use your trusted web-search to get further with this error-message... (one possibility is a RAID with the other drive - so be careful to not loose data stored on the other drive!) **||** if you are sure that the second drive can be completely deleted you may try `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb` as a last resort to easily delete everything and start from the beginning. **||** or you may rework your question or ask a new one not about installing, but about recovering your inaccessible harddrive.