# Unable to format external drive (udisks-error-quark, 0)

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive, external-hdd

I am trying to format my external hard drive which contained some important data and was earlier formatted as `exFAT`. The external hard drive (Transcend 1TB) was bought 6 months prior and it does not get mounted on Ubuntu. But the drive is visible in `disks utility`. Following is the image:

[image: Disk]

I tried this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/377253/unable-to-format-usb-drive-with-disks-udisks-error-quark-0) for solution as the question contained the same error as I am getting while formatting the hard disk.

As per the link stated I installed `gparted` after opening it gives me error `Input/Output error during read on /dev/sdb`.

I ignored the error and after I select my device from drop down of gparted following image is the outcome.
[image]

Can I retrieve my data and device? If I can not retrieve my data can I format the disk for reuse?

Or is the disk completely damaged?

Comment: Have you installed the utilities that enable Linux to read and write to exFAT? They are exfat-fuse and exfat-utils. However if you are running Ubuntu 20.04 you shouldn’t need them. Also it’s not clear in your question if you need to recover data from the disk or just format it. Either way the utilities mentioned above should enable you to do both.

Comment: @PonJar packages you mentioned are already installed and I was using this hdd on same pc earlier. My first priority would be to get data from the disk.

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing because if you format the disk you will not be able to recover any data without using specialist tools. I’ve seen other questions this week with a similar problem. What kernel are you running? uname -a in terminal will tell you. Also let us know what version of Ubuntu are you running.

Comment: @PonJar assuming I don't want to get my data. How can I format my disk. Result from `uname -a` `Linux HP-Z600-Workstation 4.4.0-178-generic #208-Ubuntu SMP` Using Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: I solved the similar problem: https://askubuntu.com/a/1478086/849328

Answer (score 0):

Ok here is the result of a bit of research which may answer your question.

Generally exFAT is not seen as a reliable file system. Some people recommend NTFS if you want to share data between Linux and Windows machines

Gparted does not have fully support exFAT. It needs the util-linux package version 2.18 or above for exfat detection. Without that I doubt GParted will be able to do anything to your exFAT disk.

```
apt search util-linux
```

will tell you if you have it installed

There does seem to be an alternative driver [techrepublic article](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/try-out-this-new-linux-exfat-kernel-module-for-improved-performance/)

If you install this you may get the whole thing working although it should work with the packages mentioned in the comments above

If you are giving up on data recovery and just want to wipe the disk then fdisk should  do the job. How to use it is another question

Comment: `util-linux` is already installed.

Comment: Since it used to work I’d start to suspect a hardware issue. Can you try the drive on another computer? Even if it’s Windows you may prove if it still works or not

Comment: Not working on either Mac, Windows or Linux