# can't reformat usb drive

Tags: partitioning, usb, mount, format

I had a working usb-drive that I could use for a windows and linux pc. Today I tried to look at some saved files, but the only thing that was on the usb-drive was a .iso-file (I don't know what this is) and my usb-drive is referred to as 'DISK CARD', which I didn't do. When I use `sudo fdisk -l`, I get the following:

`Disk /dev/sdb: 1,88 GiB, 1999110144 bytes, 3904512 sectors`
`Disk model: Mass-Storage`
`Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes`
`Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes`
`I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes`
`Disklabel type: dos`
`Disk identifier: 0x00000000`

`Device     Boot Start     End Sectors  Size Id Type`
`/dev/sdb1         129 3904511 3904383  1,9G  6 FAT16`

I can copy a file to it, but when I unmount the usb-drive and plug it back in, the file is vanished.

I already tried the following:

1. Reformat it using Disks --> *error synchronizing after initial wipe: Timed out waiting for object (udisks-error-quark, 0)*
2. Delete the partition using Disks --> it automatically appears back
3. Reformat using gparted as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/377253/unable-to-format-usb-drive-with-disks-udisks-error-quark-0) --> no error, but is jumps back to as it was before.
4. Follow the instructions mentioned [here](https://lobotuerto.com/blog/how-to-format-a-usb-drive-as-fat32-in-linux/) --> everything looks the same, but when using `sudo fdisk -l`, I get the same output as before.
5. Crying --> Didn't help...

Does anyones has some other suggestions of what I can try?
Kind regards.

Comment: After a whole day of searching, I think my usb drive just broke... Best way to spend a day in quarantine

Comment: If you think it is worthwhile, you can analyze the drive according to [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144852/cant-format-my-usb-drive-i-have-already-tried-with-mkdosfs-and-gparted/933035#933035), and if you are lucky, make it work again. But your description makes me fear that the drive is 'gridlocked', which is a failure mode.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case it's not completely dead, try this:

**WARNING! HIGHLY DESTRUCTIVE! CHECK WITH FDISK THAT YOU ARE ERASING CORRECT DEVICE! SDB IS USED IN COMMAND AS QUESTION CONTAINS SDB DEVICE!**

`dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=1M count=100`

This will zero (erase) first 100MB of the usb device. If there is any partition info it's usually at start of device, and will get nuked this way.

After that try Gparted to add new partition to USB and format it.

Comment: NOTE TO EVERYONE READING: `/dev/sdb` may be something else on your PC! Note the output of fdisk above - you must use the same device name.

Comment: Ah yes, edit right away, sorry!!