# Ubuntu died and wont reboot

Tags: boot, fsck

My Asus just stopped might be the battery, but now it wont boot ubuntu,not sure how i got here but after alot of scrolling text 
I got the following message,

```
Error reading block 27263921 (attempt to read block from filesystem resulted in short read) while getting next inode rom scan.

/dev/sda2: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY.
        (i.e., without -a or -p options)
fsck exited with status code 4

The root filesystem on /dev/sda2 requires a manual fsck
```

I would be grateful of any help, what do i write?

Comment: Beyond Kaz' immediate solution, this smells like a hardware failure. See [How do I check the integrity of a storage medium (hard disk or flash drive)?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/539184/how-do-i-check-the-integrity-of-a-storage-medium-hard-disk-or-flash-drive)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your system is already telling you exactly what to do:

```
/dev/sda2: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY. (i.e., without -a or -p options) fsck exited with status code 4
The root filesystem on /dev/sda2 requires a manual fsck
```

Go get your Ubuntu Live USB and boot into it. From there:

1. Open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>)
2. Run `sudo blkid | grep ext` and try to find your drive. It should return one line, containing an ID like `/dev/sdb2` (replace this with whatever you got).
3. Using the ID you got in step 2, run `sudo fsck /dev/sdb2`. If it returns any errors, you can run `sudo fsck /dev/sdb2 -a` to actially fix your filesystem.