# All new files are erased after each reboot

Tags: 14.04, boot, filesystem, startup

I have ubuntu 14.04 installed on my 64Gb flash card. It is *not live* and I am *not guest user*, 100% sure. I don't remember how exactly I created it, but filesystem is ext4 and I have no swap. It worked fine until the day all saved files have been removed after regular reboot. So system behavior look like liveUSB. I can save/delete no files permanently. All new files are erased after each reboot. I had some issues with 'read-only file system' before (file system spontaneously turns to read-only), but simple reboot was enough to fix it. I have tried `fsck`, but I am not sure of appropriate options. Any suggestions or configuration requests are welcome. Thank you!

`df` output:

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev             2012448        4   2012444   1% /dev
tmpfs             404648     1312    403336   1% /run
/dev/sda1       60793916 52100200   5589104  91% /
none                   4        0         4   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs              65536     1272     64264   2% /tmp
none                5120        0      5120   0% /run/lock
none             2023236      292   2022944   1% /run/shm
none              102400       40    102360   1% /run/user
tmpfs              10240      780      9460   8% /var/log
```

`sudo lsblk -f` output

```
NAME   FSTYPE LABEL MOUNTPOINT
fd0                 
sda                 
└─sda1 ext4         /
sr0
```

`sudo lsblk -m` output:

```
NAME     SIZE OWNER GROUP  MODE
fd0        4K root  floppy brw-rw----
sda     58,9G root  disk   brw-rw----
└─sda1  58,9G root  disk   brw-rw----
sr0     1024M root  cdrom  brw-rw----
```

`sudo e2fsck -cf /dev/sdb1` output

```
    e2fsck 1.42.9 (4-Feb-2014)
Checking for bad blocks (read-only test):   0.00% done, 0:00 elapsed. (0/0/0 err
done                                                 
/dev/sdb1: Updating bad block inode.
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information

/dev/sdb1: ***** FILE SYSTEM WAS MODIFIED *****
/dev/sdb1: 662079/3866624 files (0.5% non-contiguous), 13244484/15441152 blocks
```

Comment: Please edit your question, and add the output of the following three command lines (in a terminal window), `df` , `sudo lsblk -f` , `sudo lsblk -m`

Comment: better, post the output of fsck from a live boot and also the health of your hard drive with smartmontools - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools . Sounds as if your hard drive is failing. See also http://askubuntu.com/questions/539184/how-do-i-check-the-integrity-of-a-storage-medium-hard-disk-or-flash-drive

Comment: @sudodus I have included the required information

Comment: The posted information does not really help me that much. Can you look at the links I gave you.

Comment: "How do I check the integrity of a storage medium (hard disk or flash drive)?" - http://askubuntu.com/questions/539184/how-do-i-check-the-integrity-of-a-storage-medium-hard-disk-or-flash-drive . What is your question ? testdisk supports some usb drives so ....

Comment: OK, you are right, you have an installed system without swap, which should be OK in a computer with enough RAM. I would suggest that you use following fsck command. Boot Ubuntu *live* from another drive, or insert the card into another computer with linux. Make sure that the ext4 partition is *not* mounted. `sudo e2fsck -cf /dev/sdx1` Now the drive letter x is a, but in the live system or another computer, it will probably be another letter, maybe b or c. Check that with `lsblk` (as before).

Comment: @sudodus please take a look at my `e2fsck` output. It seems that my drive is not totally broken, is it? I don't completely understand whether `fsck` is used to repair the drive or just check it?

Comment: The file system was modified, but only minor modifications, that it 'dares' do without asking you. Overall it looks good. I don't think the file system is causing your problem. - Now that there are some minor modifications, maybe you can keep saved files again. At least you can try. Boot, create a small file and reboot. Is it still there? - Otherwise I have one concern - the file system is rather full, 91% used. I think it will work better if you remove (or move to another drive) enough files, to reach below '80% used', as seen by `df`.

Comment: You can also run the command `sync` to flush the buffers. Wait until the prompt returns. And shutdown the computer after that. It should increase the chance that the files are really saved before things are turned off.

Comment: @sudodus I still can't save any files permanently (after `fsck`). Also I can't delete any files to free space. I have tried `sync` earlier with no effect.

Comment: Have you got another drive, where you can backup your important files? The pendrive might be failing. It looks like it is getting close to 'gridlock', or maybe it is already gridlocked. Another alternative is that the operating system is damaged (a software damage). After backing up the important files, you can wipe the whole device with mkusb. It can release lock-ups in the internal system of the pendrive - It has a small processor inside, and we cannot reach it with our tools, but we can release the load by letting things go to zero and let it replace failing memory cells with fresh ones.

Comment: See this link about *pendrive lifetime*. It applies to memory cards too. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2196858&p=13199297#post13199297

Comment: @sudodus mkusb is not able to wipe anything on my drive. All files are exists as before after mkusb wipe (with no errors) and remount. I tried to format it with GParted with no success also. When I remount it I see old ubuntu files. It seems that my flash drive became useless.

Comment: Now I am convinced that your USB pendrive is damaged, probably gridlocked as described at http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2196858&p=13199297#post13199297 - Please save your data to another drive as soon as possible, before the drive is completely dead.