# WD My Passport Ultra external drive is not detected by Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: boot, partitioning, mount, hard-drive

On Jan 20, I embarked on a mission of installing or adding Ubuntu to my windows 10 resident operating system. When I was installing, it gave me options what I wanted. I opted for both windows 10 and Ubuntu along. I finished installing Ubuntu. But Windows 10 disappeared 100%, no trace of it.

But I  continued to use the Ubuntu. My external hard drive was working fine day one of Ubuntu. But the next day, it did not show up on the menu as usual. Apparently, I did take out or unplugged the EHDD without permission from Ubuntu. Someone told me Ubuntu does not like EHDD being pulled out without permission? I am not sure if that is the cause of not able to detect `WD My Passport Ultra` EHDD.

However I have tried many attempts to do remounting the devices from the cli or CLIT or command line interface terminal. But nothing is working so far. I am not able to see any file. If I lose my data, it will be a big disaster. I also run Ubuntu smart test, and I did run all  those tests.  The tests nothing wrong with device. I also tried different computers with windows 10, 7 and they could not anymore detect it. I can only access the device from device manager in windows 10 and 7.

I did enter `dmesg`. I got this error as output:

```
[    3.212657] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[    3.212660] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 53 00 10 08
[    3.213956] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[    3.213959] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[    3.215583] scsi 6:0:0:1: Wrong diagnostic page; asked for 1 got 0
[    3.215596] scsi 6:0:0:1: Failed to get diagnostic page 0xffffffea
[    3.215603] scsi 6:0:0:1: Failed to bind enclosure -19
[    3.215639] ses 6:0:0:1: Attached Enclosure device
[    8.184127]  sdb: sdb1
[    8.189221] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
[    8.352638] random: nonblocking pool is initialized
[   32.994999] NET: Registered protocol family 38
[   85.349681] EXT4-fs (dm-1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode.
```

and this is the result of `lsblk`:

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:16   0 931.5G  0 disk 
└─sda1   8:17   0   128M  0 part 
sr0     11:0    1   1.4G  0 rom
```

Is there anyone who had similar problem, and had the experience first hand and solved a problem like this? Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: May you also include the result of `lsblk` in your question?

Comment: Thank you for  the advice. I  did and I got the following:

Comment: Thank you for  the advice. I  did and I got the following: lsblk

 After I typed lsblk  I got this: does it mean all my file is gone?

sdb                  8:16   0 931.5G  0 disk  
└─sdb1               8:17   0   128M  0 part  
sr0                 11:0    1   1.4G  0 rom

Comment: Please add these information in your question (edit it and add these information at the end) It seems you have your partitions are not recognized by the system.

Comment: @Mostafa,  thank you gain for the  prompt response. what  do you think might be the solution for such problem?  Any idea?

Comment: I don't know why you don't include the result of `lsblk` in the question. I have almost same problem [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/871604/external-hdd-suddenly-stopped-working). In my case, I don't even get that partition you get. Please run those commands and see what you get.

Comment: You comment  add field does not allow me to add. It is not because I am lazy.   I  tried to do it, but bounced back and I  added it as question because that allows me to post the whole information.  But you marked it duplicate. I am confused how to use the blog now.

Comment: At the bottom left hand side of the question, there should be the word 'edit' written in grey. If you click on it, it should allow you to edit your question or if you click this -> [edit]. To get the best out of the site it's a good idea to take the [tour]. Also remember all of the people answering questions on here are volunteers, not site staff. Good luck, hope you find the answer!