# WD My Passport USB Drive not recognized

Tags: usb

I have gone through other similar questions, but none of the solutions helped.
My External USB drive doesnt work any more.

lsusb:

```
Bus 001 Device 023: ID 1058:0730 Western Digital Technologies, Inc. My Passport Essential (WDBACY)
```

dmesg:

```
[ 4788.172750] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] 625076224 512-byte logical blocks: (320 GB/298 GiB)
[ 4788.173424] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[ 4788.173429] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 47 00 10 08
[ 4788.174077] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[ 4788.174085] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[ 4788.183673]  sdb: sdb1
[ 4788.186056] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
[ 4800.611506] usb 1-1.2: reset high-speed USB device number 19 using ehci-pci
[ 4805.743321] usb 1-1.2: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[ 4821.387265] usb 1-1.2: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[ 4821.575546] usb 1-1.2: reset high-speed USB device number 19 using ehci-pci
[ 4822.405581] usb 1-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 19
[ 4822.411861] scsi 4:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[ 4822.411873] scsi 4:0:0:0: [sdb] killing request
[ 4822.411893] scsi 4:0:0:0: [sdb] FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 4822.411899] scsi 4:0:0:0: [sdb] CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 5d bf 70 00 00 08 00
[ 4822.411905] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 6143856
[ 4822.411962] blk_partition_remap: fail for partition 1
[ 4822.411965] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb1, logical block 6141808, async page read
[ 4822.411969] blk_partition_remap: fail for partition 1
[ 4822.411971] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb1, logical block 6141809, async page read
[ 4822.411974] blk_partition_remap: fail for partition 1
[ 4822.411975] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb1, logical block 6141810, async page read
[ 4822.411979] blk_partition_remap: fail for partition 1
[ 4822.411980] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb1, logical block 6141811, async page read
[ 4822.411984] blk_partition_remap: fail for partition 1
[ 4822.411986] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb1, logical block 6141812, async page read
[ 4822.411989] blk_partition_remap: fail for partition 1
[ 4822.411990] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb1, logical block 6141813, async page read
[ 4822.411993] blk_partition_remap: fail for partition 1
[ 4822.411995] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb1, logical block 6141814, async page read
[ 4822.411997] blk_partition_remap: fail for partition 1
[ 4822.411999] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb1, logical block 6141815, async page read
[ 4822.913500] usb 1-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 20 using ehci-pci
[ 4823.652804] usb 1-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=1058, idProduct=0730
[ 4823.652810] usb 1-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 4823.652815] usb 1-1.2: Product: My Passport 0730
[ 4823.652818] usb 1-1.2: Manufacturer: Western Digital
[ 4823.652822] usb 1-1.2: SerialNumber: 575831314142303639393835
[ 4823.653453] usb-storage 1-1.2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 4823.653709] scsi host4: usb-storage 1-1.2:1.0
[ 4825.714633] scsi 4:0:0:0: Direct-Access     WD       My Passport 0730 1012 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[ 4825.715495] scsi 4:0:0:1: Enclosure         WD       SES Device       1012 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[ 4825.718301] sd 4:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[ 4825.718521] ses 4:0:0:1: Attached Enclosure device
[ 4825.718711] ses 4:0:0:1: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 13
[ 4831.665344] ses 4:0:0:1: Wrong diagnostic page; asked for 1 got 8
[ 4831.665351] ses 4:0:0:1: Failed to get diagnostic page 0x1
[ 4831.665355] ses 4:0:0:1: Failed to bind enclosure -19
```

After trying a few things, in between the usb got listed, but still could not open it and it randomly kept throwing "Operation is already pending" error.

Is there any way I can save the data and fix the disk?

**UPDATE**:

```
Smartctl open device: /dev/sdb1 failed: No such device
caissa@caissa:~$ sudo smartctl -a /dev/sdb1
smartctl 6.6 2016-05-31 r4324 [x86_64-linux-4.15.0-39-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Vendor:               WD
Product:              My Passport 0730
Revision:             1012
Compliance:           SPC-4
User Capacity:        320,039,026,688 bytes [320 GB]
Logical block size:   512 bytes
Serial number:        WX11AB069985
Device type:          disk
Local Time is:        Tue Dec  4 23:12:12 2018 IST
SMART support is:     Unavailable - device lacks SMART capability.

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
Current Drive Temperature:     0 C
Drive Trip Temperature:        0 C

Error Counter logging not supported

No self-tests have been logged
```

Comment: thanks! Randomly it seems to connect/disconnect, but never shows files. smartctl output added to original post

Answer (score 1):

**You have defective hardware**: Replace it immediately.

The log shows that disk is unreliable

Example: `[4822.411999] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb1` It's not that your system *cannot find* with the drive, the drive is returning errors...a common indication of hardware failure. [Thanks, @ThomasWard]

The smartctl output shows that the disk interface lacks capability for further investigation.

You might be able to save some data from the disk, but that's a hardware and data-recovery issue. There is no magic Ubuntu incantation to fix broken hardware. There are many, many relevant threads already on AskUbuntu about how to recover data from a dying drive.

Comment: To echo this answer, the problem @AAP can be seen in all of those `[4822.411999] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb1` messages.  This in indicative of defective hardware or a dead disk.  Replace the device, and don't use this current external USB drive.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar situation also, probably because the device was removed inappropriately, without unmount. From `journalctl  -xe -p 3`

```
scsi 2:0:0:1: Wrong diagnostic page; asked for 1 got 8
scsi 2:0:0:1: Failed to get diagnostic page 0x1
scsi 2:0:0:1: Failed to bind enclosure -19
sd 3:0:0:0: Wrong diagnostic page; asked for 1 got 51
sd 3:0:0:0: Failed to get diagnostic page 0x1
sd 3:0:0:0: Failed to bind enclosure -19
sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
```

I *Check Filesystem* with GNOME Disks (`gnome-disks`) and had some errors. Fixed with the repair option:

[image: screenshot]

More info [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/539185/349837).

Answer (score 0):

Well in my case I just had to rename the volume group of my wd-drive. I can't explain why this is the reason but the scans (like `lvscan`) showed that everything was right. Here's the answer which helped me: [mount unknown filesystem type 'lvm2_member'](https://askubuntu.com/questions/766048/mount-unknown-filesystem-type-lvm2-member)

Answer (score 0):

Try different USB port

Why?
WD passport (possibly) has usb-c input + usb-3.0 adapter. Try different usb-c input on  your PC/NTB and if problem is still there, try also different type of USB port via that adapter

In my case the behavior was consistent with broken disk - on Windows and Ubuntu. I was prepared to ship it back before I tried this. Using adapter with different port instead of usb-c solved issue for me. It seems that in this case, my motherboard was the issue