# Impossible to detect or retrieve files from this external HDD

Tags: hard-drive, external-hdd

I'm trying to recover an external My Passport hard drive. Nothing happens when plugged in of course.

I typed the command `ls /dev/ | grep sd` before and after plugging in the HDD, the list is the same. Moreover, you can see that there is a real problem when checking `sudo fdisk -l`, the process freezes and does not finish when this HDD is plugged in, but works fine when a working HDD is plugged in.

*What can I do to try to recover the files?*

a `sudo dmesg | tail -n 50` shows:

```
[11051.954963] usb 1-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 10 using ehci-pci
[11052.149134] usb 1-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=1058, idProduct=259f, bcdDevice=10.14
[11052.149140] usb 1-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[11052.149145] usb 1-1.2: Product: My Passport 259F
[11052.149149] usb 1-1.2: Manufacturer: Western Digital
[11052.149152] usb 1-1.2: SerialNumber: 575835314538353838344659
[11052.149657] usb-storage 1-1.2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[11052.149945] scsi host1: usb-storage 1-1.2:1.0
[11053.164076] scsi 1:0:0:0: Direct-Access     WD       My Passport 259F 1014 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[11053.164867] scsi 1:0:0:1: Enclosure         WD       SES Device       1014 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[11053.168941] sd 1:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[11053.169232] ses 1:0:0:1: Attached Enclosure device
[11053.169467] ses 1:0:0:1: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 13
[11058.469799] ses 1:0:0:1: Wrong diagnostic page; asked for 1 got 8
[11058.469811] ses 1:0:0:1: Failed to get diagnostic page 0x1
[11058.469818] ses 1:0:0:1: Failed to bind enclosure -19
[11058.471405] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] 1953458176 512-byte logical blocks: (1.00 TB/931 GiB)
[11058.472406] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[11058.472408] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 47 00 10 08
[11058.473385] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[11058.473389] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[11058.531854]  sdb: sdb1
[11058.535093] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
[11078.903902] usb 3-1: USB disconnect, device number 3
[11078.907261] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[11078.910629] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[11078.910633] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 63 6d 70 00 00 08 00
[11078.910634] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 6516080
[11078.910649] buffer_io_error: 498 callbacks suppressed
[11078.910650] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc1, logical block 814254, async page read
[11078.910780] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Synchronize Cache(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
```

Comment: does `sudo dmesg | tail -n 50` list anything about it when you plug it in?  does /var/log/* have any logs that get updated when you plug it in? we need error messages to start ;-)

Comment: Hi Rinzwind :)
Sure, I was waited for some requests. I edit my main message of what gave `sudo dmesg | tail -n 50`. What can I check in `/var/log/*` ?

Comment: in /var/log do a `tail -n 50 {file}` where {file} is the last one updated (so from  `ls -ltr`) BUT the dmesg is probably enough.

Comment: ha found a dupe after answering https://askubuntu.com/questions/871604/external-hdd-suddenly-stopped-working :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[11078.910649] buffer_io_error: 498 callbacks suppressed
[11078.910650] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc1, logical block 814254, async page read
```

That is in indication it is a hardware failure. The only way to get this fixed is to of to a hardware repair shop and see if they can replace the broken part.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot, I'll see if a repair shop can do something. So for my education, this error indicates that the OS tried a somewhat i/o ping with the HDD and got an error ?

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: USB2 cable *might* still work

I had a similar problem with my "My Passport" (WDC WD10TMVW-11ZSMS0). At some point it started to be unstable. It was capable to mount, but after a minute or so it started to produce  *I/O errors* (`Buffer I/O error`, `Failed to get diagnostic page 0x1` etc.) very similar to yours. `Smartctl` diagnostics was quite clear though, if run within few seconds after the device connect.

After replacing the original USB3 (wide MicroB) cable with USB2 (narrow MicroB) one borrowed from my phone charger, I have got a slow but stable connection, and was able to recover the data overnight.