# error:failure reading sector 0x802 from 'hd0'

Tags: boot, data-recovery, grubrescue

When I rebooted my Ubuntu 14.04 it gave the following error. I tried `ls`  and it still threw the error below. Could some one give me an exact answer on how to solve this issue? I need this help a bit urgently.

What is the best method I can use which will help me to at least get data from my `/home` folder and then I can format this disk if it is really failing?

Here is the error

```
grub rescue> ls (hd0, msdos1)
(hd0, msdos1) : Filesystem is unknown.
error: failure reading sector 0x802 from 'hd0'.
grub rescue>
```

Please help me correctly to solve this issue. I just need data from my `/home` folder once that is done I can format the disk and reinstall.

Comment: Formatting the disk won't help if the disk is failing. Replacing the disk will help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I check the integrity of a storage medium (hard disk or flash drive)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/539184/how-do-i-check-the-integrity-of-a-storage-medium-hard-disk-or-flash-drive)

Comment: You'll need to use a Ubuntu live system for that if you can't boot from the internal drive.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the drive is failing. You will likely be able to confirm [this way](https://askubuntu.com/questions/528072/how-can-i-check-the-smart-status-of-a-ssd-or-hdd-on-current-versions-of-ubuntu-1) booted from live media. In order to attempt recovery of the data you will likely find [this Q &A](https://askubuntu.com/questions/463076/partitions-disappeared-after-power-loss-while-installing) useful. If you get read errors in your attempt to create a forensic image of the drive, `ddrescue` may save your bacon.

If anything about this answer is unclear, drop me a comment and I'll do my best to provide clarity.