# Can't mount my new usb?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, usb, mount

I'm a newbie on linux, I have always been a windows user but I'm studying computers engineering and am interested in this OS.

When I try to mount my usb flashdrive, it's a Kingston 16 gb USB 3.0 and I've been saving my work to it for 1 or 2 weeks, then I wanted to boot this usb and install windows 10 to my laptop, so I saved all my work to a cloud storage and formatted it, I saw some tutorials of how to format a usb and make it bootable from linux. I formatted it as ntfs using the Gpart tool and all right but suddenly it stopped working properly...

It started with some performance issues, like, sending something to this usb and then in the middle of the process it stops, or it slows down really hard. Some people told me to install some ntfs tools and use the command :
`ntfsfix /dev/sdc1` 
but it does not work, also I tried to use chkdsk /f on windows and didnt help, then I went to disks and changed the mounting settings of the usb but nothing helps... The error which displays  more frequently is this:

```
Error mounting system-managed device /dev/sdc1: Command-line `mount 
"/mnt/70A8F74026A4133E"' exited with non-zero exit status 13: 
ntfs_mst_post_read_fixup_warn: magic: 0x00000000  size: 1024   
usa_ofs: 0  usa_count: 65535: Argumento inválido
ntfs_mst_post_read_fixup_warn: magic: 0x00000000  size: 1024   
usa_ofs: 0  usa_count: 65535: Argumento inválido
ntfs_mst_post_read_fixup_warn: magic: 0x00000000  size: 1024   
usa_ofs: 0  usa_count: 65535: Argumento inválido
ntfs_mst_post_read_fixup_warn: magic: 0x00000000  size: 1024   
usa_ofs: 0  usa_count: 65535: Argumento inválido
$MFTMirr does not match $MFT (record 0).
Failed to mount '/dev/sdc1': Error de entrada/salida
NTFS is either inconsistent, or there is a hardware fault, or it's a
SoftRAID/FakeRAID hardware. In the first case run chkdsk /f on Windows
then reboot into Windows twice. The usage of the /f parameter is very
important! If the device is a SoftRAID/FakeRAID then first activate
it and mount a different device under the /dev/mapper/ directory, 
(e.g.
/dev/mapper/nvidia_eahaabcc1). Please see the 'dmraid' documentation
for more details.
(udisks-error-quark, 0)
```

And when i use the command "ntfsfix /dev/sdc1" it says:

```
Mounting volume... ntfs_mst_post_read_fixup_warn: magic: 0x00000000              
size: 1024   usa_ofs: 0  usa_count: 65535: Invalid argument
ntfs_mst_post_read_fixup_warn: magic: 0x00000000  size: 1024   
usa_ofs: 0  usa_count: 65535: Invalid argument
ntfs_mst_post_read_fixup_warn: magic: 0x00000000  size: 1024   
usa_ofs: 0  usa_count: 65535: Invalid argument
ntfs_mst_post_read_fixup_warn: magic: 0x00000000  size: 1024   
usa_ofs: 0  usa_count: 65535: Invalid argument
$MFTMirr does not match $MFT (record 0).
FAILED
Attempting to correct errors... 
Processing $MFT and $MFTMirr...
Reading $MFT... OK
Reading $MFTMirr... ntfs_mst_post_read_fixup_warn: magic: 0x00000000  
size: 1024   usa_ofs: 0  usa_count: 65535: Invalid argument
ntfs_mst_post_read_fixup_warn: magic: 0x00000000  size: 1024   
usa_ofs: 0  usa_count: 65535: Invalid argument
ntfs_mst_post_read_fixup_warn: magic: 0x00000000  size: 1024   
usa_ofs: 0  usa_count: 65535: Invalid argument
ntfs_mst_post_read_fixup_warn: magic: 0x00000000  size: 1024   
usa_ofs: 0  usa_count: 65535: Invalid argument
OK
Comparing $MFTMirr to $MFT... FAILED
Correcting differences in $MFTMirr record 0...OK
Correcting differences in $MFTMirr record 1...OK
Correcting differences in $MFTMirr record 2...OK
Correcting differences in $MFTMirr record 3...OK
Processing of $MFT and $MFTMirr completed successfully.
Corrupted file $UpCase
Rewriting $UpCase file
$UpCase has been set to default
Setting required flags on partition... OK
Going to empty the journal ($LogFile)... OK
Failed to sync device /dev/sdc1: Input/output error
Failed to fsync device /dev/sdc1: Input/output error
Error reading bootsector: Input/output error
Failed to sync device /dev/sdc1: Input/output error
Remount failed: Input/output error
```

What i should do? is the usb officialy dead?

Comment: You can try https://askubuntu.com/questions/539184/how-do-i-check-the-integrity-of-a-storage-medium-hard-disk-or-flash-drive to check if the drive suffers from hardware damage.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your USB is dead. Try formatting it or replacing with a new one.

```
$MFTMirr does not match $MFT (record 0).
Failed to mount '/dev/sdc1': Error de entrada/salida
NTFS is either inconsistent, or there is a hardware fault, or it's a
SoftRAID/FakeRAID hardware. In the first case run chkdsk /f on Windows
then reboot into Windows twice. The usage of the /f parameter is very
important! If the device is a SoftRAID/FakeRAID then first activate
it and mount a different device under the /dev/mapper/ directory, 
(e.g.
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the hardware is bad, but the fact the errors started after a format I would try a few things first.

**Troubleshoot tools:**

- dmesg -- `man dmesg` for usage. cli program
- lsusb -- `man lsusb` for usage. cli program
- fdisk -l -- `man fdisk` for usage. cli program
- dd   -- `man dd` for usage. cli program
- mkfs -- `man mkfs` for usage, cli program
- gparted -- help --> contents for usage. gui program

**1: Use a USB 2.x port on your computer. Just in case it is an USB 3.0 issue..**

**NOTES:**

- *MUST* have the correct device name in /dev/sdX. Very easy to overwrite a 'good' drive this way.
- These commands and programs require root or sudo privileges.

**2: Delete all partitions *AND* the partition table from the thumb and start over.**

***A: Zero out the partition table.***

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdx bs=512 count=4
```

This will write zeros to the first 2MB of the thumb drive erasing the partition table.

Only the first 512 bytes required but we want to remove any old boot loaders, partition, and file systems...

***B: Create partitions (use cli "fdisk" or gui "gparted"***

*1: Create partition table type "msdos".*

```
fdisk /dev/sdX
o   create a new empty DOS partition table
```

*2: Create partition.*

```
n   add a new partition
p   primary
partition number 1 default
First sector -- default
Last sector -- default
w   write table to disk and exit
```

*3: Format partition.*

I would use a linux friendly filesystem for this test. Fat32 or ext3.

`mkfs -t ext3 /dev/sdX1`

or

`mkfs.vfat /dev/sdX1`

**C: Retest USB thumb drive by moving files.**

Comment: If this works you can look at [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/294023/fat32-ntfs-isofs-on-usb/294247#294247) answer to make a bootable USB drive that works for windows and linux.