# Limit on bad sectors in USB drive?

Tags: usb-drive, hardware-test

I recently ran on a USB drive the `f3write`, `f3read`, and `f3probe` tests. The size of the drive is legitimate, but there are some corrupted sectors indicated in `f3read`:

```
Data OK: 7.49 GB (15697680 sectors)   
Data LOST: 124.00 KB (248 sectors)  
Corrupted: 124.00 KB (248 sectors)  
Slightly changed: 0.00 Byte (0 sectors)  
Overwritten: 0.00 Byte (0 sectors)
```

The `f3probe` run shows the proper size of the drive:

```
Device geometry:  
*Usable* size: 7.50 GB (15728640 blocks)  
Announced size: 7.50 GB (15728640 blocks)  
Module: 8.00 GB (2^33 Bytes)  
Approximate cache size: 0.00 Byte (0 blocks), need-reset=no  
Physical block size: 512.00 Byte (2^9 Bytes)
```

Am I correct in thinking that any bad sectors mean return this drive to the seller? Or do all USBs have a certain number of bad sectors?

Comment: I returned the USB drive to the seller, who exchanged it. I did take evidence of the bad sectors, which may have smoothed things. New USB tests fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not normal, it shouldn't have any bad sectors.

If the drive is new then returning it to the seller [makes sense](https://www.linuxbabe.com/command-line/f3-usb-capacity-fake-usb-test-linux).

If the drive has been around awhile then repairing it is worth a try [using `fsck`](https://www.maketecheasier.com/repair-corrupted-usb-drive-linux/).

Comment: See also [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/59064/349837) an [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/539184/349837) posts for more tools to check integrity of the drive.