# How to fix boot issues on HP Laptop with Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: boot, 16.04, hp

On an older Laptop, an HP Compaq 8510w, I recently installed Ubuntu 16.04 as the sole OS. The installation worked, and Ubuntu runs on the machine.

However, when switching on the laptop, sometimes the boot process works as expected, and sometimes I run into an unknow sort of error. Then I have to switch the laptop off, reboot it, try to boot normally, try to boot in recovery mode, try again, until the boot process finally finished. Then there are days, you switch the laptop on, the the boot process just works without any problems.

Below I post photos of the error message (if helpful at all) and some of the boot configurations. I appreciate some help in order to find the potential problem of these boot issues, and how to fix them.

Additional information:

- A startup HDD and RAM check did not reveal any problems.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Addendum 11 Dec: After having tried for about 20 minutes to boot the laptop, an internal error was indicated on the GUI. Not sure if this error has something to do with the boot problems, I will post screenshots from the error here:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you tried adding `acpi=off` to your grub?

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I will try to follow the steps as shown in http://askubuntu.com/questions/160036/how-do-i-disable-acpi-when-booting . I will see how this works in the next days...

Comment: @Alex, Could you run a [memtest](https://askubuntu.com/questions/591488/how-do-i-run-memtest86/) and [smart data hdd test](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59064/how-to-run-a-checkdisk)

Comment: Do you have SATA drives? You may be running in IDE mode, better to use AHCI. But HP does not call it that? With XP my system had AHCI off. When I added SSD, I had to turn it on and XP stopped working. http://h20564.www2.hp.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=emr_na-c00758841

Comment: Hardware problem.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a hardware problem

Answer (score 1):

since your problem happens "sometimes" and "randomly" and your hardware is old, I can bet it is a hardware issue.

I think in the same way you get a successful boot, you can't recognize any hardware problem... try again and again with memtest86 or similar, until you find the problem