# Unable to Remove Directory

Tags: permissions, delete, rm

I have a directory on the system, it's "**Part IX**". I'm unable to remove it by any method. I tried with "*sudo rm -rf Part\ IX*", this give me error saying

```
rm: cannot remove 'Part IX': Input/output error
```

Then I did "*ls -la*" and it gives me this

```
drwxrwxrwx 1 dilip dilip    0 Mar 29  2016 ..
d????????? ? ?     ?        ?            ? Part IX
```

So basically, none of the user, group or others have any kinds of permission on it. I tried with chown and chmod (but again, none of the user have any permission, so even that can't be done).

Please let me know if there any alternate method to remove this directory.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like a hardware problem with the disk.

Please execute the GUI scan-disk / check-disk and fix the disk.

More info here: [how-to-run-a-checkdisk](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59064/how-to-run-a-checkdisk)

After the disk will be fixed, you can check if the directory exists, and if so - remove it.

Comment: Please don't answer questions with just a link to another question, leave a comment, unless your answer adds something substantial.