# Can't boot freshly installed Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: boot, 18.04, system-installation, kernel

I recently downloaded Ubuntu 18.04 from the official Ubuntu website. I used Etcher to convert my flash drive into a bootable Ubuntu live USB. I installed Ubuntu 18.04 on my SSD, and later when the screen said to reboot, Ubuntu was unable to load. Random boot messages appeared saying there was some error.

[image: screenshot after installation when I rebooted my laptop]

Every time I tried to install Ubuntu the same thing happened. I went for the dual boot for the next time, but after getting that error I removed Windows from the SSD and tried to clean install Ubuntu, but the same thing happened.

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! This looks like corrupted system data. Have you [verified the installer](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu)? Have you run a [disk check](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59064/how-to-run-a-checkdisk) (can be done from the installer’s live session)? Can you boot into the [recovery mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92556/how-do-i-boot-into-a-root-shell)? Please [edit] your question to include results.

Comment: the problem was in bios. I did not configure it correctly. I had to make a new boot profile in bios so it can boot the os.

Comment: If you have solved your problem, please post an answer (or close/delete your question). [Self answers](https://askubuntu.com/help/self-answer) and [accepting](https://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer) them are welcome here!

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in BIOS. It wasn't configured correctly. A new boot profile had to be made in BIOS so that it could boot Ubuntu.