# How to run a thorough check on a computer drive with `fsck`?

Tags: fsck

I have booted a computer from a Ubuntu USB stick and I want to use `fsck` to make a thorough check of the entire `/dev/sdb2` disk. Just running

```
sudo fsck /dev/sdb2
```

returns almost immedeately. But I want to check the entire disk. What options to use to do so (and to have verbose information to see the check is still going on)?

Summary:

- Thorough check of the harddrive `/dev/sdb2`
- Verbose information
- Using `fsck` (or some similar command which is included in a Ubuntu 18.04 live iso)

Comment: You can use `-V` option to see more verbose information. Check `man fsck` for more.

Comment: and how to run a 'thorough' check so that the whole disk is checked?

Comment: Check [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59064/how-to-run-a-checkdisk) for possible solutions on how to check discs.

Comment: Thanks - I will try all of the ten different possibilities given in that other post.