# dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting: package 'libistack-commons-java' Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, java

[GParted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6MJq.jpg)

[SMART Data & SelfTests 01](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GocfC.jpg)

[SMART Data & SelfTests 02](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C2XIt.jpg)

[Terminal Badblocks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I38si.jpg)

I'm in Ubuntu 18.04, and now I'm dealing with this "fatal error" in dpkg folder, while trying to install some random apps... Some of them are returning this error:

```
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 reading files list for package 'libistack-commons-java': Input/output error
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

I don't know exactly what this pack "libistack-commons-java" does, but since is something wrong with it, I supposed I could update this pack and get rid of all potencial corrupted archives or something like this.

Then I got the same error, and I don't really know what else I could try!

```
guialleoni@guialleoni:~$ sudo apt-get update -y
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [88,7 kB]
Hit:2 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                
Get:3 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [88,7 kB]
Get:4 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease [74,6 kB] 
Fetched 252 kB in 6s (39,2 kB/s)                                               
Reading package lists... Done
guialleoni@guialleoni:~$ sudo apt-get install -y libistack-commons-java
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libistack-commons-java is already the newest version (3.0.6-3~18.04).
libistack-commons-java set to manually installed.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
guialleoni@guialleoni:~$ sudo apt update && sudo apt install libcanberra-gtk-module libgconf-2-4
Hit:1 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Get:2 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [88,7 kB]   
Get:3 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease [74,6 kB] 
Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [88,7 kB]    
Fetched 252 kB in 1s (236 kB/s)     
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
5 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libgconf-2-4 is already the newest version (3.2.6-4ubuntu1).
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libcanberra-gtk-module libcanberra-gtk0
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/17,9 kB of archives.
After this operation, 84,0 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package libcanberra-gtk0:amd64.
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 reading files list for package 'libistack-commons-java': Input/output error
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

Some big heart to help the dummie here? Please!

Comment: `Input/output error` means a possible hardware failure, among other (less-likely) possible causes. Look up how to run a SMART test on your hard drive.

Comment: See [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59064/how-to-run-a-checkdisk/59077#59077) question on how to run SMART tests, it might be a bit old but the information still looks accurate.

Comment: Edit your question and show me screenshot(s) of the `Disks` application `SMART Data & Tests`. It may take two screenshots to get all of the data. Also show me `grep -i sda /var/log/syslog*`. Report back. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them.

Comment: @heynnema 

Hey, guys! Thanks for your availability. I'm running Check for bad blocks right now... I've already edited the question with the SMART Data & Tests prints!

Im also trying to understand exactly how to proceed with the `grep -i sda /var/log/syslog*` that @heynnema asked... I think I'll have to wait till the checking finish...

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I've reviewed your SMART data... You're probably checking for bad blocks incorrectly. Exactly what command did you use? Is this a laptop or desktop computer? The `grep` command is run from within the `terminal` app.

Comment: @heynnema I'm checking this way right here: 

`sudo badblocks -sv /dev/sda`

 then, i'd run this: 

`sudo badblocks -sv /dev/sda > bad-blocks-result sudo fsck -t ext4 -l bad-blocks-result /dev/sda1`

 I'll print the terminal right now and edit in the question

Comment: From `man badblocks`... Important  note:  If  the output of badblocks is going to be fed to the
       e2fsck or mke2fs programs, it is important that the block size is prop‐
       erly  specified,  since  the block numbers which are generated are very
       dependent on the block size in use by the filesystem.  For this reason,
       it  is  strongly recommended that users not run badblocks directly, but
       rather use the -c option of the e2fsck and mke2fs programs.

Comment: @heynnema `done                                                 
Pass completed, 52 bad blocks found. (52/0/0 errors)`

That was the output from badblock check... That means my HD is ruinned? Thats chocking considering that the notebook went from dell assistance few weeks ago, and since then I did not use it... I just made a test...

Comment: Yes, but your test did a read-only test, and bad blocks a normally found on a write cycle, which you didn't do. See my answer for the correct way to do a bad block... and I'll bet you find more bad blocks. Report back.

Comment: status please...

Answer (score 0):

Note: do NOT abort a bad block scan!

Note: do NOT bad block a SSD

Note: backup your important files FIRST!

Note: this will take many hours

Note: you may have a pending HDD failure

Boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB.

In `terminal`...

`sudo fdisk -l` # identify all "Linux Filesystem" partitions

`sudo e2fsck -fcky /dev/sdXX` # read-only test

or

`sudo e2fsck -fccky /dev/sdXX` # non-destructive read/write test **(recommended)**

The -k is important, because it saves the previous bad block table, and adds any new bad blocks to that table. Without -k, you loose all of the prior bad block information.

The -fccky parameter...

```
   -f    Force checking even if the file system seems clean.

   -c    This option causes e2fsck to use badblocks(8) program  to  do  a
         read-only  scan  of  the device in order to find any bad blocks.
         If any bad blocks are found, they are added  to  the  bad  block
         inode  to  prevent them from being allocated to a file or direc‐
         tory.  If this option is specified twice,  then  the  bad  block
         scan will be done using a non-destructive read-write test.

   -k    When combined with the -c option, any existing bad blocks in the
         bad blocks list are preserved, and any new bad blocks  found  by
         running  badblocks(8)  will  be added to the existing bad blocks
         list.

   -y    Assume  an answer of `yes' to all questions; allows e2fsck to be
         used non-interactively.  This option may not be specified at the
         same time as the -n or -p options.
```

Comment: Ok, then! I'll try that! This could take a while but I'll keep you posted! Thanks! Now I just realize that I get the same error trying to install YUMI...I've gotta do that on windows... hahaha

Comment: @GuilhermeAlleoni from Windows, do `chkdsk /f c:` and `chkdsk /r c:` from an admin console.

Comment: I found out that somehow I lost Windows in this machine... Which were in dual boot with Ubuntu... It might take longer than I thought but i'm going through this!! Hhahaha I'll keep you posted!

 I didnt get this commands:
from Windows, `do chkdsk /f c:` and `chkdsk /r c:`

Comment: Show me a screenshot of `gparted`.

Comment: I tried to boot Windows to check it's disk manager, but it forced me to run some kind of HDD check. Anyway I did lost windows (not a problem actually), and then I had to erase the disk completely and install Ubuntu again...

Since I'm not quiet sure if there is some pending HDD failure, I think it's safer to check for Bad blocks anyway, isn't it?

ps: I've edited the post with `gtparted` print

Comment: @GuilhermeAlleoni yes, since there's no data on the drive now, go ahead and bad block the disk. Report back.