# Firefox and nautilus crash (bus error?)

Tags: 18.04, nautilus

I am running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on a Dell Inspiron 15 7559. 
I had been having issues with putting my computer to sleep by closing the lid (I think it's related to my GPU). Last night I closed it inadvertently and got errors such as

```
acpi INT3400:00: Unsupported event [0x86]
psmouse serio1: elantech: failed to write register 0x07 with value 0x01
psmouse serio1: elantech: failed to initialise registers.
psmouse serio1: elantech: failed to put touchpad back into absolute mode
NVRM: Xid(PCI:0000:02:00): 79, GPU has fallen off the bus.
```

I didn't pay much attention to it as it's happened in the past. I restarted manually, Ubuntu proposed some updates that I downloaded and applied.

Next I Firefox crashed any time I tried to download anything. `killall firefox` didn't do anything and I was forced to restart every time.

Now I notice that nautilus crashes, I can't open it directly. Running `strace nautilus` finishes with

```
munmap(0x7ff4c1973000, 46084)           = 0
munmap(0x7ff4c197f000, 1)               = 0
access("/run", F_OK)                    = 0
stat("/run", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=940, ...}) = 0
access("/run/user", F_OK)               = 0
stat("/run/user", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=80, ...}) = 0
access("/run/user/1000", F_OK)          = 0
stat("/run/user/1000", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0700, st_size=320, ...}) = 0
access("/run/user/1000/dconf", F_OK)    = 0
stat("/run/user/1000/dconf", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0700, st_size=60, ...}) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/run/user/1000/dconf/user", O_RDWR|O_CREAT, 0600) = 16
pwrite64(16, "\0", 1, 1)                = 1
mmap(NULL, 1, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, 16, 0) = ?
+++ killed by SIGBUS (core dumped) +++
Bus error (core dumped)
```

In the last lines.

I ran `sudo nautilus` and it works, although now I am aware I shouldn't have done it.

I have no clue what is going on and can't find similar cases online, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First of all try reinstalling faulty apps by:

```
sudo apt purge nautilus && rm -fr ~/.local/share/nautilus
sudo apt purge firefox && sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt clean && sudo apt update && sudo apt install nautilus firefox
```

Reinstall your GPU drivers

But you could also [check](https://askubuntu.com/a/395349/925971) your disk for bad sectors:

```
sudo badblocks -sv /dev/sdXY  > bad-blocks-result
```

And fix them, if required:

```
sudo fsck -t ext4 -l bad-blocks-result /dev/sdXY
```

And to kill an application use `killall -9 firefox`. It will terminate it forcefully. It is if your application could not be stopped just by `killall firefox` command.