# Ubuntu 18.04 crashed all of sudden. Can anyone help me to figure out the problem and resolve this?

Tags: fsck, inode

Error appears like this:

```
Integrity: problem loading X.509 certificate-65
Ima: Error communicating to TPM chip
/Dev/sdb1 contain a file system with error,check forced.
Inodes that were part of corrupted orphan linked list found.
```

Comment: What is the relation to your tags? The error message indicates a corrupt hard drive, I'd first backup important files to an external drive, then run a live session and [check the disk](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59064/how-to-run-a-checkdisk). Maybe you need to replace the hard drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem this morning. It have been resolved by doing a `fsck` on the corrupted disk. Hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks. This is the same i followed yesterday and yes it resolved my issue!

Comment: Great! You should then accept the answer... It's a good practice, @Sachin. :)