# Showing "Press 'Ctrl'+'C'" to cancel filesystem checks in progress

Tags: boot, 20.04

My Ubuntu OS system got switched off suddenly due to a power cut. After that when I restart the system, it is showing Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to cancel filesystem checks in progress and it is showing same message from 5 days onwards.Even I am unable to enter the terminal.please help me, I have my data and personal documents are there in the same system. please help me fix this issue.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you let it finish the check or do you stop it each time?

Comment: it has been 5 days so i am trying to forcibly stop it to skip this process but not getting any wy

Comment: Could be a dead drive

Comment: please help on fixing this....

Comment: Look at this questions first answer and it will walk you through the steps of several disk checking steps. https://askubuntu.com/questions/59064/how-to-run-a-checkdisk Have a live CD or DVD ready to boot from as you will need it.

Comment: no i donot have @David

Comment: Then you need to download the iso and make 1 you need it. What happened to the one you installed from?

Comment: i already deleted it

Comment: David i got live usb what to do next please suggest, i donot want to loose my personal data. please suggst