# Grub sometime don't let me start system

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

fwends,

I have installed windows 10 next to ubuntu 20.04.2LTS also I've added below kernel parameter

```
acpi_osi=linux acpi_backlight=intel
```

Without this parameter, I wasn't able to change brightness (laptop LENOVO LEGION)

Sometimes not actually know when I have got a screen like in the below link (google photos) I need to restart by the hard shutdown (hold power switch) and by now second run always work but I feel like it just luck.

Also, I have set three seconds default boot but I saw that sometimes is 30 instead of 3. I changed it by a package called `grub-customizer`

Anyone had a similar problem or can give me any advice on how to avoid it?

**Thank you** in advance!

**Link**: https://photos.google.com/share/AF1QipOdI-Ry7C5YIe6T-3o9sXljW3-PRsyxzW3TeXLtUe5ugDinDLT0kClOpuMDepstQw?key=dUxQbDlZWFRQd2xfeHhPR0lqY3pLa2tBU2taVmt3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message visible in your first and forth screenshot explains what is causing your issue:

```
Failure: File system check of the root filesystem failed
```

It also tells you what is needed to fix the problem:

```
The root filesystem on /dev/nvme0n1p2 requires a manual fsck
```

Thus what you will need to do is type the following command at the (initramfs) prompt:

```
fsck -yf /dev/nvme0n1p2
```

This will check your root filesystem for errors and fix them, I would recommend running the command again if any errors are found to verify the filesystem is healthy.

One other concern however is that you mention this is happening repeatedly, this really should not be the case. One potential cause of this other than repeatedly improperly shutting down your system could be a dying disk drive.

If the issue continues to recur then I would suggest taking the time to perform diagnostics on the drive to check it's health. There is already a good answer elsewhere on the site explaining how you can go about this so I would suggest reading here for help with that [How to run a checkdisk?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59064/how-to-run-a-checkdisk/539185#539185)

Note that a failing drive could also be the cause of the other freezes you mention so I do strongly recommend taking the time to run the above diagnostics as soon as possible. This will also give you chance to safely back up your data before the drive fails completely in the event that it is on it's last legs.