# How do I remount a file system as read/write in linux?

Tags: read-only

How do I remount a file system as read/write in linux from read only
needed for dev/sda6 ext4,
OS is Dual boot but window is not running
Ubuntu 22.04.1

Comment: If a file-system *flips* from RW to RO, there will be a reason, and until you deal with that reason, you'll find it *flip* from RW to RO again & again so why not explore the problem now.  You've not provided any OS/release details, plus *file-system* details which matter with these type of issues.

Comment: [Edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1447065/edit) and add the following: the distro and version of Linux, if dual boot with Windows, if dual boot, find out if fast boot is turned on in windows (this is the default) if the partition is in an external or internal drive, if external, if it was unplugged insanely, the type of filesystem, NTFS, exFat, ext4, etc.,

Comment: What is the mount point of `/dev/sda6`? Is it `/` or `/home`? If not, can you unmount the partition?

Comment: See [this question and all the answers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59064/how-to-run-a-checkdisk) for how to check for problems in the drive.

Comment: Mounted on /, /var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell

Comment: Snap packages are RO and cannot be mounted RW intentionally (*so as to prevent corruption or malicious changes*).  If a problem with a *snap* is found, you re-create the *snap* package to fix it.  Snap mounts use no disk space (*they exist on the file-system and the `mount` you see for them just points to the existing copy*)

Comment: I Assume that you have mounted "/dev/sda6 /home ext4 defaults 0 0" in read only mode in fstab and now you want to mount it in read write mode then try mount -o remount,rw /home this will help for your.

Comment: @guiverc Ignore the `, /var/snap/...`.  It's a side effect of snap bind-mounting the **host**-hunspell `/usr/share/hunspell` to there.